# Error when fetching URL: One of the sub-directories is removed on get request

Tags: java, get-request

When attempting to send a get request to the url https://student.utm.utoronto.ca/timetable/api/courses/20199/, I get this error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=https://student.utm.utoronto.ca/api/courses/20199
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:760)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:757)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:705)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:295)
    at com.github.Bb0lt.utmtimetablebuilder.model.CourseFinder.main(CourseFinder.java:30)
```

I noticed that in the error, the URL is not the same as the original one specified in the request. "/timetable" has been removed from the directory.

This probably has to do with the fact that the website is blocking webscraping, as the robots.txt file at https://student.utm.utoronto.ca/robots.txt is specified. I tried setting a user-agent, but I still get this error.

Here is the code I've tried:

```java
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Host", "student.utm.utoronto.ca");
            headers.put("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
            headers.put("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none");
            headers.put("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

            Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://student.utm.utoronto.ca/timetable/api/courses/20199/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36")
                    .headers(headers)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();
```

What can I do to get access to the page? do I need to use a proxy?

Comment: The URL is not the same because the original URL returns `301 Moved Permanently`. That is, it redirects to the second URL you specified. But that URL does not exist. This is a configuration problem on the server side. You can't access it from a browser, either, can you?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am able to access it from my browser, it's only when I try to reach the first URL through code that I get that second URL

Comment: Well, on my browser it just gets to "404 Not Found". So maybe you have some cookie set in your browser, that prevents it from redirecting.

Comment: do you think if I set cookies that exist in my browser it may solve the problem?